# facebook events start_time doesnot return correct value

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

start_time value returned using fql from java code is different than the one returned from graph explorer .

fql:

```
fql?q={"events":"SELECT eid, name,description, start_time, end_time, pic_small,pic_big, eid,venue,location from event WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() and start_time > 1347482366)" ,"locations":"select page_id,location from page where page_id IN (select venue.id from #events)" ,"rsvpStatus":"select eid, rsvp_status from event_member where eid IN (select eid from #events) AND uid = me()"}
```

java code result :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "events",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "eid": 495493753795633,
          "name": "Yo yo party",
          "description": "",
          "start_time": **1347656400**,
          "end_time": **1347670800**,
          "pic_small": "http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/static-ak\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yy\/r\/XcB-JGXohjk.png",
          "pic_big": "http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/static-ak\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yn\/r\/5uwzdFmIMKQ.png",
          "venue": {
            "id": 154409375600
          },
          "location": "PIKE PLACE FISH MARKET"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "locations",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "page_id": 154409375600,
          "location": {
            "street": "86 Pike Place",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "WA",
            "country": "United States",
            "zip": "98101",
            "latitude": 47.608639747653,
            "longitude": -122.3405485174
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "rsvpStatus",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "eid": 495493753795633,
          "rsvp_status": "attending"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

graph explorer result :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "events",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "eid": 495493753795633,
          "name": "Yo yo party",
          "description": "",
          "start_time": "**2012-09-14T14:00:00-0700**",
          "end_time": "**2012-09-14T18:00:00-0700**",
          "pic_small": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yy/r/XcB-JGXohjk.png",
          "pic_big": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yn/r/5uwzdFmIMKQ.png",
          "venue": {
            "id": 154409375600
          },
          "location": "PIKE PLACE FISH MARKET"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "locations",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "page_id": 154409375600,
          "location": {
            "street": "86 Pike Place",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "WA",
            "country": "United States",
            "zip": "98101",
            "latitude": 47.608639747653,
            "longitude": -122.3405485174
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "rsvpStatus",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "eid": 495493753795633,
          "rsvp_status": "attending"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are the issues :

1. Time format difference
2. The start_time and end_time returned to the java code is incorrect. When I converted the unix time stamp it turns out to be one hour less than the actual event start and end time.

Is this  a known issue? Any information would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The graph API explorer result is UTC -7 according to the Timestamp
Is this just that the FQL result is a unix timestamp in UTC-8? (this was the default on Facebook until recently, and not all apps will have the correct timezones - i think this is a migration option in the app settings)